# Matrix multiplication in knitr code chunk

Tags: r, latex, knitr

When I include an inline code trunk using `\Sexpr{}`, the matrix multiplication symbole `%*%` is interpreted as Latex commenting. How to get around this?

Comment: Are you using LaTeX-style rather than Rnw-style syntax? See (linked) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746684/can-i-use-a-knitr-inline-expression-in-the-title-of-a-latex-document?rq=1

Comment: so, since you've accepted my answer -- have you figured out what your actual problem was?

Comment: I didn't actually have a problem -- I was re-installing the entire tex-live so I couldn't test before posting the question. The problem is a concern I had in my mind that turned out not true.

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but maybe you should test such surmises before posting them to StackOverflow ...

Comment: I agree. It was my fault completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable concern, but it doesn't happen to me (with R-devel/3.1.0, knitr 1.5). Also, logically it seems as though it shouldn't happen since the contents of code chunks are evaluated before LaTeX sees the file. Reproducible example please?

(As shown below, you can get into trouble if you try hard enough, but generally I think you shouldn't.)

If `texmult.Rnw` is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

hello

<<>>=
m <- matrix(1:4,nrow=1)
x <- 1:4
@

The result is \Sexpr{m %*% x}

This is a bad thing: \Sexpr{"%*%"} and then more stuff

\end{document}
```

Then `library(knitr); knit2pdf("texmult.Rnw")` gives me

[image]